# awk not assigning strings or substrings

Tags: linux, awk

I've written an awk script to parse the output of log file into a tsv for excel, and everything is working fine. Then I wanted to add one more column to the tsv by extracting a substring from a field. But I can't for the life of me get awk to pull out that substring, or even assign the field to variables. I spent a few hours trying to figure out what's going on to no avail. Here is the portion of the script that is driving me batty:

```
                    printf("$0=%s\n", $0);
                    printf("$1=%s\n", $1);
                    printf("$2=%s\n", $2);
                    inputLine = $0;
                    cmd = $1;
                    wavFile = $2;
                    printf("inputLine=%s\n", $inputLine );
                    printf("cmd=%s\n", $cmd );
                    printf("wavFile=%s\n", $wavFile );
                    uScore = index($wavFile, "_" );
                    printf("uscore=%d\n", uScore );
                    ucNum = substr($wavFile, 9, 13 );
                    testPhrase = substr($2, index($2,"_")+1, length($2) );
                    printf("ucNUm = %s\n", $ucNum );
                    printf("testPhrase= %s\n", $testPhrase );
```

and here is the output produced:

```
$0=Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
$1=Loading
$2=uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
inputLine=Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
cmd=Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
wavFile=Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
uscore=13
ucNUm = Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.....

Thanks Ed for those tips. I now have the variables assigning correctly. But I am still not getting the substring assigned. Here is the updated script:

```
                    printf("$0=%s\n", $0);
                    printf("$1=%s\n", $1);
                    printf("$2=%s\n", $2);
                    inputLine = 0;
                    cmd = 1;
                    wavFile = 2;
                    printf("inputLine=%s\n", $inputLine );
                    printf("cmd=%s\n", $cmd );
                    printf("wavFile=%s\n", $wavFile );
                    uScore = index($wavFile, "_" );
                    printf("uscore=%d\n", uScore );
                    ucNum = substr(wavFile, 1, $uScore );
                    testPhrase = substr(wavFile, $uScore+1, length($wavFile) );
                    printf("ucNum = %s\n", $ucNum );
                    printf("testPhrase= %s\n", $testPhrase );
```

and the revised output:

```
$0=Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
$1=Loading
$2=uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
inputLine=Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
cmd=Loading
wavFile=uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
uscore=5
ucNum = Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
testPhrase= uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav
```

I have tried extracting the ucNum string with both substr(wavFile, 1, uScore) and substr($wavFile, 1, $uScore) and neither extract the substring. Any other thoughts?

Comment: Here is a sample input line: "Loading uc60_why_is_that_blinking.wav" and I am trying to extract "uc60" into the variable ucNum.

Comment: Always include sample input and expected output in your question, not as a comment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `$` in front of the awk variables and so undesirably getting the field referenced by the integer value of the variable instead of simply the value of the variable (or `$0` if the variable is unset or it's content is non-numeric).

```
$ echo "foo bar" | awk '{x=1;       print "[" x "]\t[" int(x) "]\t[" $x "]"}'
[1]     [1]     [foo]

$ echo "foo bar" | awk '{           print "[" y "]\t[" int(y) "]\t[" $y "]"}'
[]      [0]     [foo bar]

$ echo "foo bar" | awk '{z="stuff"; print "[" z "]\t[" int(z) "]\t[" $z "]"}'
[stuff] [0]     [foo bar]
```

Look at your code and note the difference between the print statement that does what you want:

```
printf("uscore=%d\n", uScore );
```

and any of the ones that don't, e.g.:

```
printf("ucNUm = %s\n", $ucNum );
```

Btw the trailing semi-colons are doing nothing, and the parens aren't doing what you think and could just be removed too:

```
printf "ucNum = %s\n", ucNum
```

or even just:

```
print "ucNum =", ucNum
```

Comment: Got it! Re-read your comments a little closer and saw that I was using "$" in print statements where I shouldn't have been. Everything working now as expected. Thanks for your help!!